# WCF DataContract Deserialization missing 3 String fields even with Order set

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, serialization, deserialization

I have a service which receives data from a proxy hosted in a WebApp. The DataMembers are set with Order=* and I've also tried adding isRequired=true. The problem is that out of 60 fields of information serialized and deserialized, the same 3 String fields are consistently missing (null). I've run debugging which shows me that the data makes it from the client browser to the proxy service intact (serialized from JSON). The proxy service then sends it on to the Windows service where the 3 fields are missing after deserialization.

I've tried setting the order of the fields differently but nothing seems to work. It's always the same 3 missing fields simple Strings, often no longer than 10-20 chars. It's also worth mentioning that these troublesome DataMembers are correctly populated in all other areas of the program.

The proxy service code is as follows

```
 public TransactionResult Update(MyObj obj, String ItemOne, String ItemTwo)
    {
        MyService.MyServiceClient proxy = new MyService.MyServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_IMyService");
        proxy.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        TransactionResult result = proxy.Update(obj, ItemOne, ItemTwo);
        proxy.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Windows service code is

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
public TransactionResult Update(MyObj obj, String ItemOne, String ItemTwo)
{obj is missing same 3 values at this point...}
```

An example of one of the DataMembers of the Object

```
[DataMember(Order = 56)]
    public String ItemTwo
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

- make sure these fields are not computed (and therefore reset or changed in your code, depending on deserializatin order)
- make sure you don't define a DefaultValue attribute, as serialization uses this to optimize bandwith
- make sure you don't declare some custom behavior that would hack those fields out
- try another WCF binding (HTTP, NETTCP, ...)
- hook on the OnDeserialized, OnDeserializing events and check the data is there

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check could be that the additional params in the signature have the same names as the properties on your entity.

Why not rename the signature parameters (remember to regen your client service reference / proxy)

```
public TransactionResult Update(MyObj obj, String ItemOne, String ItemTwo)
```

to

```
public TransactionResult Update(MyObj obj, String NewItemOne, String NewItemTwo)
```